# I am working on Express 4 Application on Node.js. I have having problems rendering a new view

Tags: node.js, express

I used the Express generator to generate an express 4 application. Once I did that I replaced the jade templating engine with ejs. I am now trying to add a new route at /players. When I try and navigate to myapp/players I am receiving this error :

```
    Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/home/fk/d/e/goose/views"
       at EventEmitter.app.render (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:555:17)
       at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
       at module.exports (/home/fk/d/e/goose/app.js:65:7)
       at Layer.handle_error (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:58:5)
       at trim_prefix (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:300:13)
       at /home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
       at Function.proto.process_params (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
       at IncomingMessage.next (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
       at fn (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:933:25)
       at EventEmitter.app.render (/home/fk/d/e/goose/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:557:14)
```

My file structure is

```
    |Myapp"goose"
     -bin
     -config
     -node modules
     -public
     -routes
     --index.js
     --users.js
     --players.js
     -views
     --index.ejs
     --users.ejs
     --players.ejs
     --error.ejs
     -app.js
     -package.json
```

Here is the code contained in my app.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var routes = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var players = require('./routes/players');

    var app = express();

    var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/players', players);


    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });


    module.exports = app;
```

Here is the code for my routes/players.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET players page. */
    router.get('/players', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('players', { title: 'Players' });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

My index view is currently still working fine. Thank you for your help in advance and please let me know if there is any more information I can provide that would be of assistance.

**EDIT 1: ** I have added an error.ejs file which is reflected above in the file structure. I believe what was causing all the error messages above was my application was trying to render the error.ejs when I was navigating to /players. Now when I am trying to navigate to /players I am being redirected to the new error.ejs view.

**Edit 2:** This problem has been solved. Please look at user Jonathan Lonowski's answer below for a detailed explanation. Thank you Johnathon.

Comment: Note that the path given to `.use()` and the route will be combined. So, `app.use('/players', ...);` and `router.get('/players', ...)` are defining the route `GET /players/players`.

Comment: You have provided the correct answer. If you would like to submit using answer this question I will gladly select your checkmark. Once I changed app.use('/players', players); to app.use( players); it worked correctly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial issue is that requesting `GET /players` will result in a `404 Not Found`.

This is because the route is defined as `GET /players/players` since Express combines the `.use()` and router paths:

```
app.use('/foo', fooRouter);
```

```
// GET /foo/bar
fooRouter.get('/bar', ...);
```

When specifying a "prefix" with `.use()`, you can define routes for the "root" of that prefix in the router:

```
// GET /players = /players + /
router.get('/', ...);
```